# vertical and horizontal parallax scrolling on same page

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, parallax, vertical-scrolling

so i'm needing to get this parallax effect down so far I've figured out the horizontal form of scrolling but can't seem to figure out horizontal scroll with scroll to and mousewheel binding.  now here's how the structure is:

[image]

so using [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/) tutorial i've gotten the vertical parallax effect down.  So then I tried to modify it to add in the horizontal.  Here's the html:

```
<!-- Home -->
<section id="home" data-speed="10" data-type="background" class="vertical">
  <article>HOME</article>
</section>

<section id="section3" data-speed="4" data-type="background" style="float:left;" >
  <article>SECTION 3</article>
</section>
<section id="section4" data-speed="4" data-type="background" style="float:left;" >
  <article>SECTION 4</article>
</section>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<!-- Section #1 -->
<section id="section1" data-speed="4" data-type="background" class="vertical">
  <article>SECTION 1</article>
</section>
<!-- Section #2 -->
<section id="section2" data-speed="4" data-type="background" class="vertical">
  <article>SECTION 2</article>
</section>
```

Now I created a function to set the scrolling:

```
function scrolling(direction){
// Cache the Window object
$window = $(window);

$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
 var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    switch(direction){            
        case "vertical":
            // Scroll the background at var speed
            // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 
            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
            break;
        case "horizontal":
            var xPos = -($window.scrollLeft() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 
            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = xPos + 'px 50% ';
    }
    // Move the background
    $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

  }); // window scroll Ends

});     
}
```

and i have a menu that would navigate to each section by first taking them to the home section and then going to the section selected.  now the scrollto is a next phase but i can't to seem to have just the basic parallax effect down, which is where I am stuck at.